# How to Assign CTRL-Super-T to BASH Shell

Tags: macos, shortcut

I would like to assign said hotkey to the BASH shell.  How can this be achieved with native High Sierra capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

- Open automator, New > Workflow/ Service.
- Add "Launch Application" to the workflow:

  [image]
- Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Right click on the General > Show in Finder. Or alternatively navigate to `/Users/you/Library/Services`.
- Copy the workflow there.
- In system Preferences, it will show up and then bind a shortcut to it.